# Error message when plotting a polynomial function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried plotting a quadratic function but an error message pops up. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]   
y = []
count = 0
while count < 9:
    y[count] = x[count]**2 + 5*x[count]
    count = count + 1
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: When I tried to copy the code, there was a formatting issue which I wasn't sure how to fix.

Comment: Insert your code, select it and use the "Code Sample" button at the top of the editor.

Comment: Highlight your code and just press Ctrl + K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of **y** is 0, which means you wouldn't be able to set the elements of **y**. You could try putting (a total of 9) 0's or whatever the 'default' value you want to use initially.

Comment: Also, is there a method to do this without manually adding all the 0s to y? If I wanted to plot a larger set of values it would be pretty tedious.

Comment: If you want all the 'default' values to be the same then you could do something like this: "y = [0] * 9".